# How to change images after entering some characters in textField

Tags: swift3

I have the following as below:

myImg1  textfield1 
  MyImg2  textfield2

**The problem for below code:**

as soon as the user tap the textfield, it CHANGE IMMEDIATELY.

```
txtfield1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


func textFieldEditDidBegin(_ textField: UITextField) {

 let newImg: UImage? = UIImage(named: :icon1")
   myImg1.image = newImg
}
```

Are the textField1 and 2 share above code or a different one for editing event?

**I need to do the following:**

when user tap or touch the textfeld1 and **after** enter some characters, then myImg1 image will change to other image

**Update:

```
How to handle textField2?  How to use this same func for these twp textfields?

txtfield1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


func textFieldEditDidBegin(_ textField: UITextField) {

 let newImg2: UImage? = UIImage(named: :icon2")
   myImg2.image = newImg2
}
```

Thanks. Please help

Comment: This is just to understand your question correctly – You are looking to change myImg1 when user enters first text in txtfield1. and you dont want this to happen for txtfield2? If so, you are already 50% done, as your method will be called only for txtfield1. you just need to use event  .editingChanged instead of .editingDidBegin, also add a check if text length is 0. this should be good. let me know if that works.

Comment: @Vivek Molkar, how to handle textField2 same as textfield1? are textField1 and textField2 share the same func textFieldEditDidBegin(_ textField: UITextField)?  how to ?

Comment: If you are looking for multiple textfields it will be better if you use [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate). [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) is the method you should use. textfield is the parameter that you can check, it will be one that is currently in use .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can use the `UITextFieldDelegate` to identify the current `textField`. Please see also Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

In your case you should have a look at the following function to identify, if the user ends typing in a dedicated `textField`: 
**Don't forget to set the `delegates` to your `txtFields`!**

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
       // Your textField
       @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldVar1: UITextField!
       @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldVar2: UITextField!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          // Don't forget to set the delegate of your available textFields
          self.txtFieldVar1.delegate = self
          self.txtFieldVar2.delegate = self
       }

       func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
          // Do some stuff based on the identified textField
       }
   }
```